# Parse timestamps in plain text file and count them per 5 minute intervals

Tags: python

My Input is a plain text file containing 6,000 timestamps, looks like this

```
2011-06-21 13:17:05,905
2011-06-21 13:17:11,371
2011-06-21 13:17:16,380
2011-06-21 13:17:20,074
2011-06-21 13:17:20,174
2011-06-21 13:17:24,749
2011-06-21 13:17:27,210
2011-06-21 13:17:27,354
2011-06-21 13:17:29,231
2011-06-21 13:17:29,965
2011-06-21 13:17:32,100
2011-06-21 13:17:32,250
2011-06-21 13:17:45,482
2011-06-21 13:17:51,998
2011-06-21 13:18:03,037
2011-06-21 13:18:04,504
2011-06-21 13:18:10,019
2011-06-21 13:18:27,434
2011-06-21 13:18:29,960
2011-06-21 13:18:30,525
...
```

My output should be a CSV file counting how many lines are found between each 5 minute slot starting at the "whole hour"

Example Output:

```
From, To, Count
13:00:00, 13:04:59, 0
13:05:00, 13:09:59, 0
13:10:00, 13:14:59, 19
13:15:00, 13:19:59, 24
...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does your file really include the extra line breaks between lines?

Comment: No it doesn't, had to insert them here so it doesn't all show up in one line.

Comment: @storm_to If formatted as a code block, it will preserve your whitespace and linebreaks appropriately.  Highlight and Ctl-K to make it a code block.

Comment: I started writing code that looks at hh:mm:ss as separate integers but quickly realized that's too complex because I'd have to account for max as 59, so decimal approach is no good. Took a look at time module docs but found no refference to any function that can do "time math" that I can do something like time+5

Comment: @storm_to: See http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html - ie `datetime.now() + timedelata(minutes=5)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is untested and you'll have to implement the time conversion functions yourself. You'll have to look in the time module for functions that does what you want. The convert_time_string_to_unix_time should convert a time string to the corresponding number of milliseconds since Jan 1st, 1970 (a standard Unix timestamp).

What it does is basically to divide time into five minute slots, loop through all the timestamps and increase the number of timestamps for that timestamp's slot with 1 for every timestamp found. Then it just iterates over all the found slots and converts them back to timestamps and also prints the number of timestamps found for that slot.

```
SLOT_LENGTH = 1000 * 60 *5
for line in file:
    slot = convert_time_string_to_unix_time(line) / SLOT_LENGTH
    bucket[slot] = bucket.get(slot, 0) + 1

for slot in sorted(bucket.keys()):
    print(
        convert_unix_time_to_time_string(slot * SLOT_LENGTH),
        convert_unix_time_to_time_string((slot + 1) * SLOT_LENGTH - 1),
        bucket[slot]
    )
```